# Conditions for convergence of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Problem statement**

For what positive values of $a$ and $b$ is

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b+1}+...+\frac{1}{b+k}}$

convergent?

**Progress:**

A necessity for convergence is that $a^{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b+1}+...+\frac{1}{b+k}} \longrightarrow 0, k \longrightarrow \infty.$ We know that $b>0$ so it follows that $\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b+1}+...+\frac{1}{b+k}>0 \ \ \forall k$ and thus $0<a<1$.

Notice that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b+k}$ is divergent(compare to $\frac{1}{k}$ and use limit comparison test). But this is not enough, we also need to know how **fast** it attends $0$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series converges when $0 < a < e^{-1}$.

Observe that $\frac{1}{b} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b+k} = \ln(b+k) - ln(b) + O(1) = \ln(k) + O(1)$ (for fixed $b$). So we're interested in the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^{\ln(k)+O(1)}$.  The terms are product of a sequence (the $a^{O(1)}$ error term) which is bounded both above and below by positive numbers with the terms of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^{\ln(k)}$. Thus our problem is equivalent to determining the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^{\ln(k)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^{\ln(a)}$.  This last converges whenever $\ln(a) < -1$, that is, when $0 < a<e^{-1}$.